# how can I pass dynamic IP address in keycloak realm redirect URL?

Tags: keycloak

I have created keycloak docker image and deployed in kubernates in my on premise server and setup localhost: as redirect URLs and when I am accessing it from other systems, it should be the IP address of that system, instead of localhost. Could you please help me to get dynamic IP setup in my keycloak from Kubernetes script?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just set the redirectUris in your realm config to `*`. Otherwise each system to be accessible needs to be added to the realm, which you can do from the admin console or through the API.

In Activiti we distribute a keycloak helm chart with a custom realm for activiti installations. In that we set redirectUris to `*` and [allow that to be overridden at install time](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/pull/32/files#diff-8e9b5b5cf988767272f16d363998e613R68). We're doing that in a helm chart but if you weren't using a helm template then you could do a `sed` to replace a string. But that is for a shareable distribution. If you've just got a single installation then I'd expect you to be adding applications/clients to the realm through the console or API.